How to split address in talend into separate columns
I want to split the below address from single column to multiple columns using talend from csv file to database table.
Input
|ADDRESS|
2660 9 SHERWOOD HEIGHTS DR W  OAKVILLE ON L6J 7Y8
Expected Output
|STREET_NUMBER | UNIT_NUMBER |STREET_NAME|STREET_DIRECTIONS|STREET_TYPE|CITY|PROVINCE|POSTAL_CODE
|2660|9| SHERWOOD HEIGHTS|W |DR|OAKVILLE|ON| L6L 7Y8 | .
To be done in talend studio. I have about 60 different rows with different addresses. They all have same city and province but only some have the direction like W or S

Use a tMap, now having said that, if your addresses have a different amount of tokens when you solit up your string, your absolute best bet for this is to use the Google Maps API, it’ll do the work for you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
